# PgAdmin4 asking for passphrases for my private keys on connect

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ssh, pgadmin-4

I am using PgAdmin 4 v3.3 on Ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to connect a PostgreSQL server somewhere else via a ssh tunnel. The credentials are correct, i tested it on a windows machine.

When I try to connect to the server it asks me for the database password and the user password, which is expected behaviour,but after entering the credentials, I am suddenly being prompted by the gnome keyring and asked to enter a passphrase for one of my private keys which have no relation to the server. I tried entering it and it just asks me the passphrase for the next one. The ssh tunneling option is using a password, not a key file. I tried to upgrade from 3.1 pgadmin4 to 3.3 version but it did not help.

Comment: Had the same issue. Switched to DBeaver and all these problems vanished immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by creating a ssh tunnel in my shell and then changing the options in the server connection.

```
ssh -L localport:dbserver_ip:remote_port user@remote
```

in pg admin i then changed the connection details to connect to `localhost` and `localport`.